# Can not connect to docker container(python server) with Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, server, virtualbox

I am studying the docker.

I using docker and using Dockerfile to run a python server.

This my python name app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello docker"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

 app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

I am running in the VirtualBox and use centos7.

If I don't add

```
host="0.0.0.0", port=5000
```

I can not connect to http://192.168.1.6:5000/ (This is my virtual IP)

but now when I using Dockerfile and run this command, I can't connect to the server.

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:2.7
LABEL maintainer ="me <me@gmail.com>"
RUN pip install flask
COPY app.py /app/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

And I inspect the container

```
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

It is succeed. But I cant connect to http://192.168.1.6:5000/

I also set the firewall to open port 5000 and reload.

Why can I connect to my VM?

Comment: `docker run –net=host imgname` works or not?

Comment: docker run -net=0.0.0.0  me/flask-hello-world 
unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -net=0.0.0.0
not work

Comment: You need the Port Keywords instead of expose. Expose open the port Inside a docker Network, but is not reachable dein outside of the Container. Port makes the Applikation from outside

Comment: I don't how to check the port.
when I using docker ps the port is the same when I using python app.py.
why I using dockerfile make a container and run will not able to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) doesn't actually publish the port. You should run with the `-p` option in order to *publish* and *map* the port:

```sh
docker run --detach -p 5000:5000 <image>
```

Comment: Thank you. I forget the relationship between Linux and docker